# Loading values from properties file dynamically in GWT

Tags: java, maven, gwt, properties, mvp4g

I am working on maven based GWT/MVP4G project. I have one property file and its corresponding interface at client side, both are named as `MyConstants.properties` and `MyConstants.java` and both are placed in a client folder. Interface is extended from `Constants` class of i18n library. I am taking required values from that property file by making its instance using `GWT.create(MyConstants.class)`. Whenever I compile and run the code it is working fine, giving me the required output.

But my main issue is, after creation of `war` of that project, if I edited that property file `MyContstants.properties` by extracting `war` and changed some content in it, then unable to access those newly edited changes.

Because I have to make those changes in project's `MyConstants.properties` file, then after recompilation and again creating new `war` then only I can access the edited changes. Is there any way to bind values dynamically to that property file, means is there any way without recompiling project can I reflect those war changes?

Please help me to get out of this problem, working on it, but unable to get the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of the `MyConstants.properties` are inserted into the JavaScript-code during the GWT compilation. After the application is compiled, the property files can be removed.

That's why changing the property file after compilation has no effect.

> `.properties` files are just intermediary files used in the compilation process.

If you want to change the values of the property file, you have to choose another way to do so.

Store your property-files on the server, create a call from your GWT application to the server, read the property file and return the values to the client.

In this case, the changes on the property file will be possible without recompiling your application.